# How to run exe file with command line arguments in Mac terminal?

Tags: python, macos

I want to run the exe file with command line arguments in Mac terminal

```
p1.exe -f input.txt
```

But im getting error -bash: p1: command not found

I have converted python file p1.py into p1.exe using

```
pyintsaller p1.py --onefile
```

And running the python file with arguments works

```
python p1.py -f input.txt
```

Comment: If that `.exe` is a Windows PE executable, it won't execute on macOS. No Windows executable will (unless you're using an emulation or virtualization layer). You'll need to package into a macOS `.app` package or build a macOS installer instead.

Comment: its a linux executable

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux executable"? Do you mean an ELF file? I don't think macOS can execute an ELF executable natively either. The native executable file format for modern macOS systems is Mach-O.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to do with Python, but is a basic command shell issue. To run an executable from the current directory, you need to use the  `./` prefix.

```
./p1.exe -f input.txt
```

Note, it's a bit odd to use a .exe extension for a Linux executable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that on Unix like systems (Linux/Unix/Solaris/MacOS). scripts can be run without explicitly invoking interpreter, if two conditions are meet:

- script file starts with this line (or similar): `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- file has executable attribute flag is set

Then you can run script like this:

```
./p1.py --onefile
```

`./` means run thing from local directory. If this is not pressent the it tries to run things located by `PATH` variable, that is why you can run interpreter `python`

Comment: My question was how to run exe file